# Passing dependencies in an array instead of one by one? Is it good?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

so this code:

```
public function __constructor(A $a, B $b, $parameter)
{
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->b = $b;
}
```

would be replaced as

```
public function __constructor(array $dependencies, $parameter)
{
    $this->a = $dependencies['a'];
    $this->b = $dependencies['b'];
}
```

wouldnt it be better?

Comment: Depends. you've potentially lost your types.

Comment: agreeing with @mkaatman, this effectively *hides* your class' dependencies, making automatic injection difficult and decreasing code portability/readability/the amount of ease in which other developers build on your code